# Scrapy Xpath returns empty result

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I tried to scrape some data from this url:https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?zip=92612

I first debugged and tested in Scrapy shell. Since I just wanted the model name of the car, I copied the Xpath from Chrome. Here is how I did this:

1. I right clicked the name of model and clicked inspect
2. I found the text of model name and copied the Xpath

After I got the Xpath, I typed the command below:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="cargurus-listing-search"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/a/div[3]/div/div[1]/h4/text()').extract()
```

But the shell returned an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to extract all the car names

```
response.xpath(//div[@class="titleWrap"]/h4/text()).extract()
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a new question. For every single page, I can only get about 15 cars' information. But if I want to get more cars' information. How can I do this?

Comment: You could add extra lines of code for pagination. Here's an article that explains that https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pagination-using-scrapy-web-scrapping-with-python/